# Want to submit large content through opera browser

Tags: php, forms, opera

When I submited a large content say 400kb file (410042 characters) through form. If working fine for Fire fox, IE 8, and Safari. But when I submitted the content through the Opera 9 browser the form not getting submitted I got blank screen.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 400k isn't particularly large - and Opera should handle it just fine. I upload both small and larger files with Opera pretty much daily.

It would be really interesting and helpful to have a look at the code - both the form you're submitting and the response. Would it be possible to share a URL?

Answer (score 0):

Set you error handling to see what the problem may be.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

This may provide insight as to whether the error is a PHP issue or an Opera issue. Also, install FireBug to examine the headers that are returned from the server when this script runs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But same form working fine with Firefox, IE and Safari. I will check as per your suggestion.